# Spark flatten SQL Row into new columns after UDAF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe on which I do a groupBy, a user defined aggregation and a library aggregation:

```
data.groupBy("var1").agg(sum("var2"), makefreqs("var3")).first
```

which produces something like:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Row = ["var1_value1", 219, WrappedArray(0.6, 0.1, 0.3)]
```

What I'd like to eventually do is convert all the rows (not just .first) into this format:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [219, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3]
```

I'm stuck on how to flatten the WrappedArray(0.6, 0.1, 0.3) into three new columns (preferably with names) in the sql.Row.  What is the smartest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can find out of the box solution to what you need in [Apache DataFu](http://datafu.apache.org/).
the method [explodeArray](https://github.com/apache/datafu/blob/master/datafu-spark/src/main/scala/datafu/spark/SparkDFUtils.scala#L539) does exactly what you need:

```
import datafu.spark.DataFrameOps._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("var1_value1",219,Array(0.6, 0.1, 0.3)))).toDF
df.explodeArray(col("_3"), "array").show
```

This will produce:

```
+-----------+---+---------------+------+------+------+
|    _1     | _2|       _3      |array0|array1|array2|
+-----------+---+---------------+------+------+------+
|var1_value1|219|[0.6, 0.1, 0.3]|   0.6|   0.1|   0.3|
+-----------+---+---------------+------+------+------+
```

Please consider that in order to evaluate how many columns to create for the array, this method evaluates the data frame - if it's expensive to compute it should be cached.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the smartest way but these are my suggestions.

One way, you can use map function but it will become an RDD so you need to convert it back to DataFrame.

```
val df = data.groupBy("var1").agg(sum("var2"), makefreqs("var3"))

// implicitly pass context to toDF
import sqlContext.implicits._

df.map { case Row(var1, sumVar2, array: WrappedArray) => 
  Row(var1, sumVar2, array(0), array(1), array(2) }
  .toDF("var1", "sum_var2", "a1", "a2", "a3")
```

If you don't like converting back and forth, you can use udf to do the task.

```
val arrayToColumn = (index: Int) => udf { (array: Seq[Double]) => array(index) }

df
  .withColumn("a0", arrayToColumn(0)(df("array_col")))
  .withColumn("a1", arrayToColumn(1)(df("array_col")))
  .withColumn("a2", arrayToColumn(2)(df("array_col")))
```